# How Can index all nodes and relation ships in full text search by neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

i want to index all nodes and relationship with all of its properties in neo4j full text search but i am unable to do. CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("indexing",["*"],["*"])

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you are able to simply attempt to call all the nodes and fields when using createNodeIndex. You need to explicitly call the nodes and properties you're interested in. If you haven't already found it you see the docs here. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-full-text-search/